# How to static link libexpat.so.1 with GCC?

Tags: linux, gcc, netbeans, g++

I want to build statically program with GCC/G++ without shared dependencies. but i don't know how to do that.

With below command in Netbeans IDE i can build with shared dependency, but in some OS can not find this library(i don't want to install on new system)

```
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/lib/libexpat.so.1
```

Comment: You can't link statically with `.so` library, you need to get a `.a`

Comment: Your "below command" doesn't do what you think it does; it should produce an executable that doesn't work _at all_ (I would expect it to crash on startup)

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for fast reply. I found libexpat library in '/usr/lib/libexpat.a' path now what is switch for compile and linking .a with gcc/g++?

Comment: @MehdiH.The argument to `-L` is a directory, not a filename. These options add to the directories that it searches for libraries when you use `-lexpat`

Comment: You don't need to use `-L` for libraries in `/usr/lib`, it's in the default library search path. So just linking statically with `-lexpat` should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To statically link a program, you need *a static library*, which is a library with a filename finished in `.a`.

Linker, by default, if using default search paths (as you do with `/usr/lib`), will select the `.so` library version *and will do a dynamic link of it*, so if you want to specify that you want some static `library`, **you'll need to specify the full path name of it**, instead of using the `-l` option. So,

```
gcc -o your_program mod_a.o mod_b.o ... /usr/lib/libexpat.a
```

is better than

```
gcc -o your_program mod_a.o mod_b.o ... -lexpat
```

(the latter will select the file `/usr/lib/libexpat.so` instead, which should be a link to `/usr/lib/libexpat.so.1`, which is normally the soname of the library, and is also a symbolic link of `/usr/lib/libexpat.so.1.xx.xx`)

## NOTE

In the examples, I'm trying to call the linker through the compiler, as the default c runtime and libraries are automatically selected by the compiler when calling this way.  If you prefer to call directly the linker, the procedure doesn't change, but then you have to add the **C** runtime module and the standard c library yourself.

## NOTE 2

If you want to statically link *everything*, then you have to use static versions of all the libraries you are going to use (they are normally installed in the same directory as the dynamic ones, so you have to specify the full pathname of all in the command line)  To cope with this in a permanent development system, you can make symbolic links to them all from another path and then specify that directory as the search path for your projects that must be statically linked.

If you allways want some library to be statically linked, just erase the `.so` link (not the `.so.X` and the `.so.X.YY` links, they are not tried by the compiler) in `/usr/lib`, and the `.a` file will be selected by default by the compiler. Of course, if you want this made for every library, you can erase all the `.so` links, but you'll end with larger executables (much larger) than the original dynamically linked versions.

Comment: Thank you, i can build statically now, but it executable size is scary, with same command in Ubuntu 13 is 2-MB and same on Ubuntu 7 is 5-MB, it seems like linker insert all function to executable,
how to compile and linking with necessary function only

Comment: of course, all libraries **are now included** in your executable.... that's the thing!!!

Comment: What do you suggest for me to link only with necessary function?

Comment: I suggest you to link statically ***only*** those libraries that are not supposed to be installed in the target system.  Anyway, it is best to install the libraries as shared than to install static binaries... That's only needed normally on embedded systems where the main libraries are not mounted at boot time, and you need some executables to run before those libraries are available (for example in a initrd image)